# Silica and Alumina polyhedrons using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone has code examples on how to draw silica tetrahedron and alumina octahedron.  I need to include them in my beamer presentation.  Graphics are not so good.  So I would like to draw them using Tikz.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** I follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon%E2%80%93oxygen_tetrahedron)

[image]

```
// silica (regular) tetradhedron
unitsize(8mm);
import solids;
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(2,1.5,5,zoom=.9,center=true);
triple A=(1,0,0), B=(0,1,0), C=(0,0,1), D=(1,1,1); // for 4 oxygen atoms
triple Si=(.5,.5,.5);  // for 1 silicon atom
triple[] points={A,B,C,D};
for(var p : points){
draw(surface(sphere(p,.2)),red);
draw(Si--(Si+p)/2,gray+4pt);
draw(p--(Si+p)/2,red+4pt);
}
draw(surface(sphere(Si,.2)),gray);
```

For silica tetrahedron, we can illustrate with a regular tetrahedron. Feel free to choose another view with `currentprojection`.

Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

[image]

```
// silica (regular) tetradhedron
unitsize(5cm);
import solids;
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(2,1.5,5,zoom=.9,center=true);
triple A=(1,0,0), B=(0,1,0), C=(0,0,1), D=(1,1,1); // for 4 oxygen atoms
triple Si=(.5,.5,.5);  // for 1 silicon atom
draw(A--B--C--D--cycle^^A--C^^B--D,gray+3pt);
draw(Si--A^^Si--B^^Si--C^^Si--D,magenta+10pt);

triple[] points={A,B,C,D};
for(var p : points)
draw(surface(sphere(p,.1)),red);

draw(surface(sphere(Si,.15)),orange);

// to see how I draw a regular tetradhedron
//draw(unitbox,lightgray);
//dot(O,red);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Another Ti*k*Z option.

I use the `calc` library to find the edges ends (where they intersect with the atoms). Then, the order in which the various elements are drawn is the key to visibility.

```
\documentclass [tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,perspective}

\tikzset
{% Styles
    O atom/.style={shading=ball,ball color=red},
   Si atom/.style={shading=ball,ball color=gray},
      edge/.style={ultra thick},
      bond/.style={ultra thick,blue}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,isometric view,rotate around z=-50]
% dimensions
\def\bd{3}                         % bond distance Si-O (center to center)
\pgfmathsetmacro\el{4/sqrt(6)*\bd} % edge length (tetrahedron)
\pgfmathsetmacro\ba{acos(-1/3)}    % bond angle
\def\rO{0.3}                       % radius, oxigen
\pgfmathsetmacro\rSi{11/6*\rO}     % radius, silicon

% coordinates
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {A,B,C}
{
  \begin{scope}[rotate around z=240-120*\ii,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \coordinate (\i0) at (90-\ba:\bd);     % center  O
    \coordinate (\i1) at (90-\ba:\bd-\rO); % surface O
    \coordinate (\i2) at (90-\ba:\rSi);    % surface Si
  \end{scope}
}
\coordinate (D0) at (0,0,\bd);             % center  O
\coordinate (D1) at (0,0,\bd-\rO);         % surface O
\coordinate (D2) at (0,0,\rSi);            % surface Si
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0,0);               % center  Si
% atoms, bonds and tetrahedron
\draw[O atom]  (A0) circle (\rO cm);
\draw[edge]    ($(A0)!\rO/\el!(B0)$) -- (B0);
\draw[edge]    ($(A0)!\rO/\el!(C0)$) -- (C0);
\draw[edge]    ($(A0)!\rO/\el!(D0)$) -- (D0);
\draw[bond]    (A1) -- (A2);
\draw[Si atom] (O)  circle (\rSi cm);
\draw[O atom]  (B0) circle (\rO cm);
\draw[bond]    (B1) -- (B2);
\draw[bond]    (C1) -- (C2);
\draw[bond]    (D1) -- (D2);
\draw[edge]    ($(B0)!\rO/\el!(C0)$) -- (C0);
\draw[edge]    ($(B0)!\rO/\el!(D0)$) -- (D0);
\draw[O atom]  (D0) circle (\rO cm);
\draw[O atom]  (C0) circle (\rO cm);
\draw[edge]    ($(D0)!\rO/\el!(C0)$) -- ($(C0)!\rO/\el!(D0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

**Update:** Improvement of tetrahedron distances, and removing the not too accurate SiO2 label as suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please note from this picture alone you cannot judge if you show a SiO2 or SiO4. Drawn like this it looks more like a orthosilicate (SiO4). To clearly indicate that it is SiO2 you would have to connect every oxygen atom to another Si atom. ([Reference](https://kou.benesse.co.jp/nigate/science/images/A13G03BB01/pic03.gif))

Comment: @Roland, thanks for pointing it. I don't know much about chemistry as you can see :-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy pure Tikz construct of a tetrahedron as a start:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    ball/.style = {circle,shading=ball,minimum width=0.152cm,ball color=gray},
    ball2/.style = {circle,shading=ball,minimum width=0.210cm,ball color=red!40},
    ball3/.style = {circle,shading=ball,minimum width=0.097cm,ball color=green!40},
    ball4/.style = {circle,shading=ball,minimum width=0.184cm,ball color=blue!40},
}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[ball] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node[ball] (B) at (-0.5,1) {};
    \node[ball] (C) at (2,0.5) {};
    \node[ball] (D) at (0.75,3) {};
    \node[ball2] (Si) at (0.75,1.5) {};
    
    \draw[] (A)--(B) -- (A)--(C) (A)--(C) (B)--(D) (A)--(D) (C)--(D);
    \draw[dashed] (B)--(C);
    %\draw[thick,blue] (A)--(Si) -- (B)--(Si) (C)--(Si) (D)--(Si); % uncomment if you want to have bonds
    
    \node[yshift=-2cm] at (Si) {\ce{[SiO4]^4-}};
   
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[ball3] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node[ball3] (B) at (3,0) {};
    \node[ball3] (C) at (3.75,0.5) {};
    \node[ball3] (D) at (4,2.25) {};
    \node[ball3] (E) at (1,1.75) {};
    \node[ball3] (F) at (1.75,2.25) {};
    \node[ball4] (Al) at (2.25,1.25) {};

    \draw[] (A)--(E) (A)--(B) (B)--(E) (B)--(C) (C)--(D) (D)--(F) (F)--(E) (E)--(D) (D)--(B);
    \draw[dashed,red] (A)--(F) (A)--(C) (C)--(F);
    
    \node[yshift=-2cm] at (Al) {\ce{Al(OH)3}};

    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Reference picture: [Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343450769_Soils_of_the_Ethiopian_highlandsElias2016/figures?lo=1) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sherif-Aboubakr/publication/271767420/figure/fig1/AS:614263194406944@1523463166374/Structure-of-a-silica-tetrahedral-sheet-up-and-an-alumina-octahedral-sheet-down-1_W640.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: it is good for sketchy imagination. Are you sure the figure fit with the description of a silica tetrahedron ? and what does the dash mean?

Comment: @Black Mild I do not really know what you want to tell me. Nearly every chemistry book I own draws it that way. So yes I am pretty sure it shows a silica tetrahedron.

Comment: why numbers `(0.75,3), (2,0.5)`, etc? `Si` is the centroid of `A,B,C,D` ?

Comment: @Black Mild Just because I drew it that way. You do not need to like it. It still is a silica tetrahedron.

Comment: Please be calm, Roland! your figures look almost the same as in most chemistry textbooks. My question is straight, not biased!