# How to draw a tetrahedral of white phosphorus

Tags: chemistry

I would like to draw a white phosphorus in my note but I cannot figure it out even with the manual. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! I don't know how you need to draw the molecule, but this post could be a start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622021/silica-and-alumina-polyhedrons-using-tikz

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple Lewis structure of white phosphorus, the following might be satisfactory. I have used the `chemfig` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[cram width=3pt]{P?[a]-[:60,2]P?[b]-[:-60,2]P?[a]<[:150]P?[a,{<}]?[b,{<}]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question is that what is the 2 means in [:60,2]

Comment: It increases the bond length. The value 2 causes the interatomic distance to be twice the default distance. I included it so the bond going to the out of plane Phosphorus would be smaller than the other ones. I should add that the tetrahedron is in no way perfect. The values for angles and bond lengths were adjusted by trial and error.